# How to send mail from iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am try to send mail from my app. I want to type(dynamically) recipient id,ccid,sub and message.

Thanks

Senthilkumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on iOS 3+
Import #import  in your view controller header.

Then:

```
-(void)showMailPanel {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

        // only on iOS < 3
    //if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] == NO)
    //  [self launchMailApp]; // you need to 

    mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailComposeViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email address1",@"email address 2",nil]];
    [mailComposeViewController setSubject:@"your subject"];
    [mailComposeViewController setMessageBody:@"your body" isHTML:YES];
    mailComposeViewController.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:mailComposeViewController animated:YES];

    [mailComposeViewController release];

}


- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Result: saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Result: sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Result: failed");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
            break;
    }
    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)launchMailApp {
{
    NSString *recipients = @"dest_email";
    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, subject];
    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
}
```

Comment: this used to send static mail id only.but i required dynamically to send. such as while app run time am able to type mail id subject and message content and then i want to send.

Answer (score 2):

You need things like this:

```
//Import this in your .h file
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

...

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailController setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Report a problem - #%@", yourUserID]];
    [mailController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"support@yourWebsite.com"]];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
```

Besides, the parent view controller (the delegate) needs to conform to the **MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate** protocol:

```
    - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
        //Extra implementation here...
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: this used to send static mail id only.but i required dynamically to send. such as while app run time am able to type mail id subject and message content and then i want to send.