# How to populate an email body from UITableView data?

Tags: ios, uitableview, email, core-data

I have a registration type form in a static cell UITableView, and when the user presses the "submit" button, I would like the information in the cells to be sent as an email to a specific email address. What method would I use to do this?

I've been searching and have only found how to upload it to a server or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the cells in the table view to get the data and use MFMailComposeViewController to send the email.

Check this for iterating through the cells in your table:
[How can I loop through UITableView's cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914183/how-can-i-loop-through-uitableviews-cells)

Check this for using MFMailComposerViewController to send email:
[How to send mail from iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942976/how-to-send-mail-from-iphone-app)